# Toggle between specific html element

Tags: jquery, html

I am having problems trying to toggle between two `<p>` tags in JQuery, I have a markup which looks like...

```
<td>
   <p>paragraph 1 <a class="descriptionToggle">Click</a></p>
   <p style="display:none;">paragraph 2 <a class="descriptionToggle">Click</a</p>
</td>

<td>
   <p>paragraph 1 <a class="descriptionToggle">Click</a></p>
   <p style="display:none;">paragraph 2 <a class="descriptionToggle">Click</a</p>
</td>
```

Every time the .descriptionToggle link is clicked it should toggle between neighbouring `<p>` tags, I have tried the following... but it does not work...

```
$("a.descriptionToggle").on("click",function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().("p").toggle();
});
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your toggle:

`$(this).parent().parent().find("p").toggle();`

Fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/Dwwtk/

Comment: No worries, it's easy to do stuff like that.  I had a `Dispose` function that called `Dispose` on itself by accident once.  Damn copy/paste!!  I had a laugh about it, though :o

Answer (score 2):

You have to put a method after the `.`. use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get a descendant element

```
$("a.descriptionToggle").on("click",function(){
   $(this).parent().parent().find("p").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("a.descriptionToggle").on("click",function(){
   $(this).parents('td').find("p").toggle();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/JJ68d/1/)**